# Wayland alternative for xorg's xdotool?

Tags: input, wayland

`xdotool` is a nice X application, I tend to use it for creating macro commands (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or something like that).

It's really easy to use and convenient, but I don't know of any Wayland compatible program like this. Is there any way to send mouse and keyboard input signals to Wayland right now similar to `xdotool` for X?

It works largely with XWayland right now, but not all commands work (such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>xev</kbd> can even read the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> input but it doesn't trigger the application termination like pressing it on the keyboard) there's also the matter of potentially not using XWayland.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381831/keyboard-emulation-in-wayland and https://askubuntu.com/questions/956640/equivalent-to-xdotool-for-wayland

Comment: workaround for text entry, use xclip to save your text in the clipboard and press the middle mouse button to insert it. Two steps but works everywhere.

Comment: @qwazix ... `xdotool` performs from a script like `bash`.  Human action is not going to replace a script.

Comment: I am currently torn between selecting dotool and ydotool as an answer, they both do what I want. dotool has a very strange syntax (echo command | dotoolc?! what the hell?) but works really well. ydotool has a less strange syntax but seems currently less actively developed and more buggy. I feel like neither is the perfect answer, but both come reasonably close enough to be one.

Answer (score 13):

There's currently no perfect solution, but there's a close one: [ydotool](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool).

It uses the [uinput](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html) interface as backend, and has no dependency on display servers.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't make it run on Ubuntu 19.04. I installed `libboost-program-options-dev`, [`libevdevplus`](https://github.com/YukiWorkshop/libevdevPlus/releases), [`libuinputplus`](https://github.com/YukiWorkshop/libuInputPlus/releases) and finally the [`ydotool` itself](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool/releases), but I'm still getting `ydotool: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Note: this requires root!

Answer (score 8):

Therer is now another option for xdotool like functioality on Wayland, the [`wtype` tool](https://github.com/atx/wtype).

More details on the Wayland protocol used by `wtype` can be found in [this blog post](https://dcz_self.gitlab.io/posts/input_method/).

Comment: This is cool, sadly it has the reverse issue of using xdotool on xwayland; the issue that it doesn't work with xwayland D:

Comment: @Cestarian in what way doesn't it work for you with xwayland?

Comment: it says so on the git page u linked to, at the bottom of the readme: To support arbitrary unicode characters, wtype generates a keymap on the fly and submits it to the compositor for distribution. Unfortunately this is broken under Xwayland as X has an upper limit on the amount of defined keycode-keysym pairs. Am I maybe misunderstanding something? it works on xwayland? (I can't really test it right now because I don't have a wayland compositor set up)

Comment: I tried it under KDE neon Plasma Wayland session, but it didn't work, displaying this message: "Compositor does not support the virtual keyboard protocol"

Comment: I tried `wtype` and it seems like, disappointingly, that the protocol it relies on (`virtual-keyboard-unstable-v1`) is currently supported by neither Gnome nor KDE. (See [here](https://github.com/atx/wtype/issues/22#issuecomment-1113273742)).

Answer (score 6):

No, such features were explicitly excluded from the Wayland design for security reasons. (Reading other programs' input is the biggest problem, but allowing fake input to be sent to other programs can also lead to troubles.)

That said, I do expect some Wayland WMs to eventually implement some sort of macros feature; after all, they *will* need to support on-screen keyboards and voice control (for accessibility).

But if such a feature existed, it would depend on which Wayland compositor you're using: Weston? KDE's KWin? GNOME Shell? Enlightenment? There is no "display server – window manager" split in Wayland; the window manager *is* the Wayland server and decides which features to implement (either as Wayland sub-protocols or as D-Bus APIs or such).

Comment: It should be possible I think to create such a program that works for all wayland compositors. Libinput forwards user input to wayland, and it is through libinput that alt+f4 and other commands that use a wayland function can be triggered. All you have to do is trick libinput into reading a macro as a keyboard or mouse input; is what I think, but I have no idea how to do it myself.

Comment: @Cestarian: You would have to create a fake input device with the kernel's uinput feature.

Comment: it shouldn't be that difficult, I recall doing it in some driver work once, maybe if I just look at that code I could figure out some way. (Although I never knew what I was doing at the time)

Comment: There was a RFC on a mailing list: [RFC: Interface for injection of input events](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2017-March/033676.html) and [Add an API for taking screenshots and recording screencasts](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98894). It sounds like the challenges could be addressed with some additional security hardening work.

Comment: What's wrong with sending fake input? I understand the security issues with *reading* another programs input, but sending?

Comment: Thankfully the constant parroting of "security reasons" did not prevent the wayland developers from adding an appropriate protocol: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mstoeckl/waypipe/blob/v0.1.0/protocols/virtual-keyboard-unstable-v1.xml

Comment: If you require special privileges such as root access for simulated device events, then it's kind of the user's decision whether to trust and enable the simulation isn't it?

Comment: I wanted to mention Kde connect. It can use android smartphone as a mouse for your desktop, even in wayland.

Answer (score 1):

There's [dotool](https://git.sr.ht/%7Egeb/dotool)

Like ydotool it uses uinput so it's linux specific but independent of X11/Wayland, and even works in TTYs.

I wrote dotool because ydotool was only designed to run as root and requires a daemon.

Comment: Does dotool work on Gnome with Mutter?